# IllegalArgumentException что не так?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Main Activity

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       ListView userList;
       TextView header;
       DBHelper databaseHelper;
       SQLiteDatabase db;
       Cursor userCursor;
       SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        header = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header);
        userList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        databaseHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // открываем подключение
        db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        //получаем данные из бд в виде курсора
        userCursor =  db.rawQuery("select * from "+ DBHelper.TABLE, null);
        // определяем, какие столбцы из курсора будут выводиться в ListView
        String[] headers = new String[] {DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DBHelper.COLUMN_YEAR};
        // создаем адаптер, передаем в него курсор
        userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
        header.setText("Найдено элементов: " + String.valueOf(userCursor.getCount()));
        userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        // Закрываем подключение и курсор
        db.close();
        userCursor.close();
    }
}
```

DBHelper

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userstore.db"; // название бд
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "users"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_YEAR = "year";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE users (" + COLUMN_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NAME
                + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_YEAR + " INTEGER);");
        // добавление начальных данных
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TABLE +" (" + COLUMN_NAME
                + ", " + COLUMN_YEAR  + ") VALUES ('Том Смит', 1981);");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Выдает:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist. Available columns: [id, name, year]`
Где я ошибся? -_-

Comment: потерялся при копировании.. Вот и я не пойму в чем дело.. Вроде как все на месте, но студия выдает такую штуку...

Comment: Может там есть какая-то колнка id в самой SQL. Попробуйте поменять строку _id на  что-то вроде person_id

Comment: Эта ошибка вообще на каком действии? На инсёрте? там же автоинкремент этой колонки и она вообще в списке вставляемых значений не упоминается..

Comment: Через правку вопроса стало понятно что проблема в символе подчёркивания `_` - в курсоре `id` без него. Почему? - надо разбираться, либо таблица была создана такой и после исправления не обновлялась, либо апи в каком-то из обращений к базе этот символ игнорирует. Тут не плохо бы заглянуть в саму базу - что там есть на самом деле. И пройтись дебаггером, чтобы выяснить на каком этапе этот символ потерялся.